# Video in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, nstextattachment

I have an editable UITextView and I want to past video from youTube in it. I need to play video during editing.
Now I made only snapshot of video I want to play. How can I override NSTextAttachment to paste button instead of image to handle tap on my video.

Comment: you want a video to play in thebackground o the uitextfield?

Comment: no, I want to attach button instead of image to my textView, or somehow to handle tap on it during editing

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, if somebody interested, firstly getting frame of image attachment

```
class WATextAttachment: NSTextAttachment {

var completionHandler:((CGRect)->Void)?

override func attachmentBoundsForTextContainer(textContainer: NSTextContainer?, proposedLineFragment lineFrag: CGRect, glyphPosition position: CGPoint, characterIndex charIndex: Int) -> CGRect {
    let superRect = super.attachmentBoundsForTextContainer(textContainer, proposedLineFragment: lineFrag, glyphPosition: position, characterIndex: charIndex)
    completionHandler?(lineFrag)
    return superRect
}
```

}

and after snapshot of video attached

```
let buttton = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
    buttton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    buttton.titleLabel?.text = link
    buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CreateArticleViewController.openVideo(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    _textView.addSubview(buttton)
    imageAttach.completionHandler = {(rect : CGRect) in
        if !CGRectEqualToRect(buttton.frame, rect) {
            var frame = rect
            frame.size.height = self.youtubeView.frame.size.height
            buttton.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Comment: you think is possible to paste directly a video instead of just an image? and if it is not possible, I Have a textView where I would insert images and videos/thumnbails of videos. I need to recognize when you click and image and when you click a video/thumbnail of video, you have any idea how this could be done?

Comment: instead of button you can paste youtube view (from library), override it's delegate methods and handle all taps. Also you can use DTCoreText library, it can parse html code.

Comment: Thanks, But IO just want insert a video from a video picker. Not from youtube.

Comment: you can use Container View, it allows open controllers in frames